# cannot update quantity in stock on database php/mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

```
<html>
<body>


    <?php
    $img='productimage';
    $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    if (!$con)
    {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    mysql_select_db("agriculture", $con);
    $qry="select product.productstock, product.name_category,  product.nameseller, product.subcategory, product.name, product.productcode, product.price, product.productimage, product.status, order_detail.quantity FROM product 
    INNER JOIN order_detail on product.serial = order_detail.productid
    ";
    while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($qry)){
    $total=$row['productstock']; 
    $quantity=$row['quantity'];
    $id=$row['serial'];
    $newTotal=$total - $quantity;

    $qry= "UPDATE product SET productstock = '$newTotal' WHERE serial='$id'";


    ?>
    <table>  

   <tr>


            <td align="center"><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td><br/>

            <td align="center"><?php echo $row['price']; ?></td><br />


            <td align="center"><?php echo $total = $row['productstock'] - $row['quantity']; ?></td> <br/>






            </tr>

   </tr>
   </form>
   <?php

  }
echo "</table>";
mysql_close($con);
?>
</body></html>
```

this is my first post.
my product stock cannot update when i buy the product. 
please help me
this is my final project. i have only 2 days to complete it.
I am having an issue trying update the database with my product.

I'm sorry if this hard to read etc. Also, I know there is security flaws in my GET/POST queries I'm just trying to get the thing to work before I start using the prepared statements or whatever they are called.

Comment: where is your code for executing your update query?

Comment: You never execute :`$qry= "UPDATE product SET productstock = '$newTotal' WHERE serial='$id'";` You also are open to SQL injections and should update your driver. Additionally you dont need PHP to do the math, mysql can do that.

Comment: you have just written the query ... run the query also usimg mysql_query $qry);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
$qry= "UPDATE product SET productstock = '$newTotal' WHERE serial='$id'";

mysql_select_db('agriculture');

mysql_query( $qry, $con );
```

instead of this

```
$qry= "UPDATE product SET productstock = '$newTotal' WHERE serial='$id'";
```

Comment: `mysql_select_db('product');`?? Why do you want the OP to change DBs?

Comment: ohh i forgot if you have already selected the db then no need to write mysql_select_db() function.

Comment: i also have error Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\agriculture\admin\try-inventory.php on line 17

Comment: Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in  on line 17

Comment: also write $qry = mysql_query($qry, $con); before while loop.

Comment: also have error. Notice: Undefined index: serial in  on line 21

Comment: Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given on line 18

Comment: $qry="select product.serial, product.productstock, product.name_category,  product.nameseller, product.subcategory, product.name, product.productcode, product.price, product.productimage, product.status, order_detail.quantity FROM product 
    INNER JOIN order_detail on product.serial = order_detail.productid
    ";
    while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($qry)){

Comment: you have to select product.serial in your query and after your query add a line $qry = mysql_query($qry, $con); and then write your while loop statement.

Comment: tq mr kumar. i appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

You have just written the query and never executed it.

Use `mysql_query` first to execute it. And for your information, `mysql_*` functions are deprecated. Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` instead

Comment: Same goes for the original select, it's never executed before the looping fetches.